# check files - count python

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def countsfunc(path, stri):
    f = open('C:\Users....\sometextfile.txt','r')
    dicts = {}
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        dicts[words[1]] = dictst.get(words[0], 0) + 1
        print countdict[word[0]]
    f.close()
```

I made a function that needs to check if the second word of every line in the text is equal to "stri". But I also want that this function will count how many times it happens.
for example the text is like:

> Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.
>
> Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.
>
> Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O.
>
> Here a moo, there a moo, everywhere a moo moo

If this shows in the shell:
`countsfunc(sometextfile, MacDonald)`
then it should print me "3"

and if:
`countsfunc(sometextfile, a)`
then just "1"

and if:
`countsfunc(sometextfile, Mac)`
then "0".

Can someone help me please? My code isn't that good, I get something else. You're more than welcome to check it out.
Thanks.

edit:
***Thanks guys, I have found the solution. Thanks anyway***

Answer (score 1):

```
def countsfunc(path, string):
    counter = 0
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            if words[1] == string: #check if the second word is equal to string
                counter+= 1
    return counter
```

Pass the filepath and your word to the function. The function will return the counter number.

Comment: You need to define string where McDonald is?

Comment: That's a syntax error

Comment: Your python interpreter can answer that for you

Comment: Ouuccchh sorry about that. Hahaha. Fixed. That was silly

Comment: @alKid What if I don't want to use "counter"? Yes, seems to be stupid, but I would like to use lists or dictionaries instead. What would you do then?

Comment: @user: That doesn't make any sense. If you really want to: `counter = {'this is pointless': 0}` ... `counter['this is pointless'] += 1` ... return `counter['this is pointless']`

Comment: A list, with the length of matches found?

Comment: @alKid Just without "counter". Just using lists or dictionaries. Why not? I mean, you can ask for the value of that key and then to get the value, which is the number of times. My second Q, is not just if I could do it, but also how... because I tried to do something like this, as one can see at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have found the solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've decied to use something like yours, without dic' or lists.

Answer (score 0):

As a one liner:

```
def count_2nd_words(lines, match):
    return sum(line.split()[1] == match for line in lines)

with open('C:\Users....\sometextfile.txt','r') as f:
    print count_2nd_words(f, 'MacDonald')
```

Comment: sure no mistake? my python says something else...

Comment: What's with the emphasis on one liners on stackoverflow?  How disappointing.  Anyway, this is going to traceback if a line has one field - surely that's not a good idea.

Comment: @dstromberg: The other answer will also raise a `KeyError`. The asker hasn't specified what should happen if I try and match a line with one word against the empty string anyway. Python's generator expressions can often express ideas much more elegantly than the corresponding loop

Comment: Thanks guys, I have found the solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

My pythonic code golf version:

```
from collections import Counter
def countsfunc(path,string):
    file = open(path,'r')
    second_words  = [line.rstrip().split(' ')[1] for line in file if line!='\n']
    print Counter(second_words)[string]
```